# Wordpress pagination URL

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to apply pagination to my custom query in Wordpress. It displays ok and "almost" works - my issue is with the path it generates.

For some reason it returns a path like so:
http://www.example.com/news/page/2

...when I actually want it to be:
http://www.example.com/news/2

Does anyone know how I can remove/modify the return to exclude the unwanted "page" folder in the URL?

Thanks!
Graham

The code of the page is as follows:

```
  <!-- Middle -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 middle">

    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>

    <?php 

    $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; 

    $query_args = array (
      'category_name' => 'news',
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'paged' => $paged,
      'posts_per_page' => 1
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="news-story-snippet">          
      <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h5>
      <p class="smaller"><?php the_date();?></p>
      <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
      <p><a class="button-small green" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Read article <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></a></p>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <nav class="prev-next-posts">
      <div class="prev-posts-link">
        <?php next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', 2 ); // display older posts link ?>
      </div>
      <div class="next-posts-link">
        <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries', 2 ); // display newer posts link ?>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 

  </div>
  <!-- END Middle -->
```